# Laravel relation ship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm confused about using it Laravel relationships. I am creating Messenger. I use following database schema. If two users chat, the messages_members table will contain two identical rows - only the user column will be different.
How should I write a User model if I need a "conversation" method where I get all the users the user has ever chatted with? I can't write a Laravel`s relationship where I would ignore the line with that Id whose owner is viewing the conversation.
I assume that to get messages in the relationship messages -> messages_members just write:

```
class MessagesMembers extends Model {
public function messages(int $limit): BelongsTo
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Message::class, 'conversation_id')
         ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
         ->limit($limit);
   }
}
```

Thank you for ideas!
[image]

Comment: Can you share the rest of your model relations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a relation with a constraint

```php
//User.php
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MessageMembers::class, 'user', 'id')
        ->where('user', '<>', $this->id);
}
```

Comment: This is not way :(

`select * from messages_members where 'messages_members.user = 1 and messages_members.user is not null and user <> 1`

Comment: Where did you get the sql from? Try using DB::enableQueryLog(); User::with('conversations')->get(); print_r(DB::getQueryLog()); and see the output for queries. Or if you have barryvdh/laravel-debugbar installed define a route with closure and put User::with('conversations')->get(); and then return view('welcome'); Then visit the page and see which queries are run.

Comment: I don't understand it any more now. I install barryvdh/laravel-debugbar and searched for all occurrences of the messages_members table and found these two (the bugbar lists both the controller and the line, so I'm sure that sql queries are generating code):
select * from `messages_members` where `user` is not null and `messages_members`.`user` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22)
select count(*) as aggregate from `messages_members` where `messages_members`.`user` = 1 and `messages_members`.`user` is not null and `user` <> 1

Comment: Are you using withCount('conversations')?

Comment: Just not, conversations method code is
`
return $this->hasMany(MessagesMembers::class, 'user', 'id')
            ->where('user', '<>', $this->id);

Comment: Call is $user->with('conversations')->get();

Comment: So then I wonder why there is a select count(*) query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225752/discussion-between-conflictboy-and-donkarnash).

Comment: I swear there is no count. Isn't this a callback in case it returns 0 results?

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you - I solve it with subquery:

```
public function conversations(int $limit = null): object
{
    $table = (new MessagesMembers)->getTable();

    return $this->hasMany(MessagesMembers::class, 'user', 'id')
        ->addSelect(['user' => function ($query) use ($table) {
            $query->addSelect('user')
                ->from($table . ' AS sub')
                ->where('user', '!=', $this->getAttribute('id'))
                ->whereRaw('`sub`.`conversation_id` = `' . $table . '`.`conversation_id`');
        }])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
}
```